# why is a thread stuck in WhitespaceBasedBreakIterator, only in Java 7?

Tags: java

Some action in an application (Samurai) runs quite slowly in Java 7 (1.7.0_45_x64), but works well in 1.6.0_34 32bit.

When waiting, this thread seems to be looping on this:

```
"AWT-EventQueue-0" prio=6 tid=0x000000001234d000 nid=0x253c runnable [0x000000001431c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at javax.swing.text.WhitespaceBasedBreakIterator.setText(WhitespaceBasedBreakIterator.java:67)
    at javax.swing.text.GlyphView.getBreakSpot(GlyphView.java:794)
    at javax.swing.text.GlyphView.getMinimumSpan(GlyphView.java:551)
    at javax.swing.text.ParagraphView.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(ParagraphView.java:731)
    at javax.swing.text.html.ParagraphView.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(ParagraphView.java:157)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.checkRequests(BoxView.java:935)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.getMinimumSpan(BoxView.java:568)
    at javax.swing.text.html.ParagraphView.getMinimumSpan(ParagraphView.java:270)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(BoxView.java:903)
    at javax.swing.text.html.BlockView.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(BlockView.java:146)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.checkRequests(BoxView.java:935)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.getMinimumSpan(BoxView.java:568)
    at javax.swing.text.html.BlockView.getMinimumSpan(BlockView.java:378)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(BoxView.java:903)
    at javax.swing.text.html.BlockView.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(BlockView.java:146)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.checkRequests(BoxView.java:935)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.setSpanOnAxis(BoxView.java:343)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.layout(BoxView.java:708)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.setSize(BoxView.java:397)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.setSize(BasicTextUI.java:1714)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.getPreferredSize(BasicTextUI.java:912)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1660)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.getPreferredSize(JEditorPane.java:1332)
    at javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout.layoutContainer(ScrollPaneLayout.java:790)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1503)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1492)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1688)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1623)
    - locked <0x0000000701400770> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$2.run(RepaintManager.java:691)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$2.run(RepaintManager.java:689)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(RepaintManager.java:688)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1676)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Let me guess: you have a huge unbroken line of text in the `JEditorPane`?

Comment: Could be a reason (displaying a huge thread dump). But my question is why is it much slower in Java 7 (minutes vs about 1 sec).

Comment: You haven't given nearly enough info for that. The code of that method hasn't changed at all between versions. Basically, you're just guessing that the key difference between your two runs is the version of Java.

Comment: Same code, different jvm's, and it breaks. Which missing information would you suggest me to give?

Comment: At least the configuration of the JVMs is different,  but I don't think that could explain the huge difference. My guess: your code is broken in a way which works on Java 6 only by accident.

Comment: Which configuration file are you talking about? Those are just two base installations (run installer; done). It's not my code, it's a random application I happen to need ( http://samuraism.jp ).

Comment: JVM configuration is steered by command-line options passed to the `java` command and, since the defaults are different between 6 and 7, *just* changing the JDK version changes the configuration. But, I wouldn't bet on that being the cause.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you mean about configuration. True, this is different between versions. Still, what missing info are you talking about?

Comment: I mean the exact code and input which leads to the problem. It very probably isn't anything general and well-known.

Comment: Just run http://yusuke.homeip.net/samurai/en/index.html under a jdk 6 and a jdk 7, feed it a thread dump, click on any link.

Comment: I can confirm this is a `BoxView#layout()` regression in Java 7. Thus, it is best to avoid anything that was made with Java's 6 (or earlier) `JEditorPane` in mind. All of these things will work terribly in Java 7 (always the difference is few seconds vs few minutes).

Comment: Any bug report or other reference?